# Display a 'warning' message when increment count goes over a certain amount in ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs

First of all, thank you in advance for your help! Hi this is my first post and question so please bear with my walkthrough

I am currently working on a food pos app. Current features have increment, decrement functions and also a shopping cart displaying items and calculated totals. Another function I need to add which is to display a warning message is shown when one item goes over a certain amount and said message disappearing and i decrement the value back. This has been problematic for me as I have split up everything in small components and getting confused where I am tracking my count. Please bear in mind I am a student who's Javascript knowledge is bare minimal at this stage and we are currently in our ReactJS module.

My app.js state

```
    constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        firstName: "",
        submitedFirstName: "",
        menuItems:[],
        cart: [],
        count: 0
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({

        menuItems :[
        {

            id:6,
            title:'Salmon',
            Cost:14,
            count: 1
        }
    ]});
}
```

Functions handling adding, deleting, and warning

```
handleAddItem(item){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.state.cart.length; i++) {
        if(this.state.cart[i].id === item.id) {
            // console.log("id of cart: " ,this.state.cart[i].id);
            item['count']++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i === this.state.cart.length) {
        this.state.cart.push(item);
    }
    this.forceUpdate()
}

handleDeleteItem(item){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.state.cart.length; i++) {
        if(this.state.cart[i].id === item.id) {
            if(item.count > 0) {
                item.count--;
            } else {
                this.state.cart.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    this.forceUpdate();
}

handleWarning(e){
    this.setState({cartItems: []});
        if(e.props.id == 5){
            if(e.props.count > 3){
                console.log('warning');
            }
        }
}
```

I am hoping to target the item salmon to display a plain message on the ui when it increments over the value 4 and have the message disappear when I decrease the value below 4.

Answer (score 0):

You must manage the display of the warning with an attribute of the state, which will be modified according to your needs.
At `console.log('warning')`, do `this.setState({warning: true})`

and when the value will be correct `this.setState({warning: false})`.
To display the message in the render, proceed as follows:

```
{this.state.warning?
   "Your warning message"
null
}
```

Your state must be like this:

```
this.state={
    firstName: "",
    submitedFirstName: "",
    menuItems:[],
    cart: [],
    count: 0,
   warning:false
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer the question! I was hoping to clarify:

    
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            firstName: "",
            submitedFirstName: "",
            menuItems:[],
            cart: [],
            count: 0,
            warning:false
        }
    }

Comment: handleWarning(e){
        this.setState({cartItems: []});
            if(e.props.id == 5){
                if(e.props.count > 3){
                    this.setState({warning: true})
                } else {
                    this.setState({warning: false})
                }
            }
    }

Comment: I think so, try to run, and let me know if it's working

Comment: So sorry it isn't and I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing. I took out the console log and have 'if setstate to true' 'else setState false

Comment: Can you update your question by putting the full code. It's going to q litle bit simple for me to help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the following code in render function

`{this.state.cart.length>4? return(<div> Your warning message</div>): null)}`

This above code will display the waning if count increases else message disappears

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! I believe this will work i just need to attached the handle function as well

Answer (score 0):

THANKYOU!

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        firstName: "",
        submitedFirstName: "",
        menuItems:[],
        cart: [],
        count: 0,
        warning:false
    }
}

componentWillMount(){
this.setState({

    menuItems :[
    {

        id:6,
        title:'Salmon',
        Cost:14,
        count: 1
    }
]});
}

    handleWarning(e){
    this.setState({cartItems: []});
        if(e.props.id == 5){
            if(e.props.count > 3){
                this.setState({warning: true})
                console.log(this.state);
            } else {
                this.setState({warning: false})
            }
        }
}

render(){
return(
      <div>
       {this.state.warning ? "Your warning message" : null }
      </div>
    );

   }
}
```